# Modificar variável ao clicar javascript e PHP

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script>
  function clica(){
    var x = document.getElementById("clica").value;
    alert(x);
  }
</script>

<?php
    for ($i=0;$i<10; $i++){ 
?>
button onclick='clica()' id='clica' value='<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></button>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Tenho este código e gostaria que a cada vez que clicar em um botão, exiba o valor numérico dele. Porém só é exibido o primeiro valor, e se eu coloco a função dentro do for, exibe apenas o último. Como devo fazer para conseguir exibir o valor certo?

Comment: você está utilizando o mesmo id para todos os botões, por isso não está funcionando. Se você modificar para `onclick="clica"` sem os parênteses poderá utilizar `var x = this.value;` dentro da função

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de colocar um ID específico para cada `button`. Então no evento `onclick` passe `this` como parâmetro.

Depois na função javascript é só pegar o número pelo valor do elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
function clica(elemento) {
  var x = elemento.value;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='clica(this)' id='clica1' value='1'>Botao 1</button>
<button onclick='clica(this)' id='clica2' value='2'>Botao 2</button>
<button onclick='clica(this)' id='clica3' value='3'>Botao 3</button>
```

O `for` dos botões pode ser corrigido colocando os IDs com o número:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){ ?>
  <button onclick='clica(this)' id='clica<?php echo $i;?>' value='<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></button>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso não queria colocar um id para cada button, recomendo usar jquery, assim iria facilitar um pouco para pegar o valor de cada botão

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
    <button class="botoes" value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></button>
<?php endfor ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.botoes').on('click', function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```